# function from a parent to a child "is not a function", but works on another child component

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, meteor

I have tried searching but I feel I am lacking the ability to properly define my question, please forgive me if it has already been answered.

In summary I am trying to build a small meteor app using react, have a few child components, I found a way to call a function within one of my child components from the parent.

The problem comes in when I follow the same method to do the same thing to my next child component, I get an error that the function I am calling is not a function.

I have checked so many times and it is all exactly the same as the previous time but for some reason doesn't seem to work.

Is there something I'm missing with react, can you call multiple functions from different children?

Thanks in advance if my absurdly vague question can be answered.

Comment: Are you able to post a [mcve] of you code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're going to need to edit your post and add some example code for us -- there's a lot of possibilities about what's wrong, and we don't want to speculate and send you down the wrong path.

Comment: its quite alot of code is there a better option that just dropping it here or is that the best option?